# My code is working when console is opened in mozilla

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

I have no idea why my code is uploading files in the folder but it is not inserting data into the database when I have closed console in mozilla and why it is working correctly when I have opened console and when I am testing code with postman.
react.js (check MakePost):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Panel() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
    const [uploadFiles, setUploadFiles] = useState(null)
    const [header, setHeader] = useState('')
    const [headerMessage, setHeaderMessage] = useState('')
    const [post, setPost] = useState('')
    const [postMessage, setPostMessage] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/galleryapi")
            .then(response => {
                setFiles(response.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/postsapi")
            .then(response => {
                setPosts(response.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])

    const MakePost = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!header || !post || !uploadFiles || uploadFiles.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        setHeaderMessage('');
        setPostMessage('');

        const formData = new FormData();
        for (let i = 0; i < uploadFiles.length; i++) {
            formData.append("gallery", uploadFiles[i]);
        }
        formData.append("header", header);
        formData.append("post", post);
        console.log("Header:", header);
        console.log("Post:", post);
        console.log("Upload Files:", uploadFiles);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/makepost', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });

            if (!response.data) {
                axios.get("http://localhost:3001/galleryapi")
                    .then(response => {
                        setFiles(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
                axios.get("http://localhost:3001/postsapi")
                    .then(response => {
                        setPosts(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            } else {
                console.log(response.data);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error making post:", error);
        }
    };

    const DeletePost = (id) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("id", id);

        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/deletepost", formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            timeout: 5000, // Set a timeout value (in milliseconds)
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    // Fetch the complete set of posts and files after a successful deletion
                    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/galleryapi")
                        .then(response => {
                            setFiles(response.data);
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/postsapi")
                        .then(response => {
                            setPosts(response.data);
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));
                } else {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="file" id="gallery" onChange={e => setUploadFiles(e.target.files)} multiple />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="header">Header</label>
                    <textarea id="header" rows="10" value={header} onChange={(e) => setHeader(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                    <b>{headerMessage}</b>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="post">Post</label>
                    <textarea id="post" rows="10" value={post} onChange={(e) => setPost(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                    <b>{postMessage}</b>
                </div>
                <button onClick={MakePost}>Submit</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
            {
                posts.map(post => (
                    (posts.length > 0) ? (
                        <div key={post.id} className='post'>
                            <div className="d-flex">
                                <b>{post.header}</b>
                                <button onClick={() => DeletePost(post.id)}>Delete</button>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <b>{post.post}</b>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                {
                                    (files.filter(file => file.postid === post.id).length > 1) ? (
                                        files.filter(file => file.postid === post.id).map(file => (
                                            <div key={`filekey_${file.id}`}>
                                                <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/gallery/${file.name}`} alt={file.name} />
                                            </div>
                                        ))
                                    ) : (
                                        files.filter(file => file.postid === post.id).map(file => (
                                            <div key={`filekey_${file.id}`}>
                                                <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/gallery/${file.name}`} alt={file.name} />
                                            </div>
                                        ))
                                    )
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ) : (<></>)
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Panel
```

node.js (check makepost route):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors')
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "top_gardering"
})

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '../client/public/gallery')
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const min = 0
        const max = 999
        cb(null, "TOP_GARDERING_" + Date.now() + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) + file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/makepost', upload.array('gallery'), (req, res) => {
    const files = req.files;
    const header = req.body.header;
    const post = req.body.post;

    const makePostSql = "INSERT INTO posts (header, post) VALUES ?";
    const postValues = [[header, post]];

    con.query(makePostSql, [postValues], (err, postResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error creating post:', err);
        }

        con.query("SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", (request, result) => {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                const lastPostId = result[0].id.toString();
                const galleryValues = files.map(fileName => [lastPostId, fileName.filename]);
                if (galleryValues.length > 0) {
                    const makeGallerySql = "INSERT INTO gallery (postid, name) VALUES ?";
                    con.query(makeGallerySql, [galleryValues], (err, galleryResult) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error inserting into gallery:', err);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("No files to insert into the gallery.");
                }
            } else {
                console.log("No posts found.");
            }
        });
    });
});

app.get('/postsapi', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC", (request, result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
})

app.get('/galleryapi', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM gallery", (request, result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
})

app.post('/deletepost', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body
    const deletepostsql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?"
    con.query(deletepostsql, [id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        const getFilesNamessql = "SELECT name FROM gallery WHERE postid = ?"
        con.query(getFilesNamessql, [id], (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle the error
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }

            result.forEach(element => {
                const fileName = element.name;

                // Check if the file exists
                fs.access(`../client/public/gallery/${fileName}`, fs.constants.F_OK, (accessErr) => {
                    if (!accessErr) {
                        // File exists, unlink it
                        fs.unlink(`../client/public/gallery/${fileName}`, (unlinkErr) => {
                            if (unlinkErr) {
                                // Handle the error if unable to unlink the file
                                console.error(`Error unlinking file ${fileName}:`, unlinkErr);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Handle the error if the file doesn't exist
                        console.error(`Error accessing file ${fileName}:`, accessErr);
                    }
                    const deleteGallerySql = "DELETE FROM gallery WHERE postid = ?"
                    con.query(deleteGallerySql, [id], (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    })
})

app.post('/sendmessage', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
    const header = req.body.header
    const message = req.body.message
    const makeMessageSql = "INSERT INTO messages (header, message) VALUES ?"
    const messageValues = [[header, message]]
    con.query(makeMessageSql, [messageValues], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
})

app.get('/messagesapi', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC", (request, result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
})

app.listen(port)
```

console message after submit and refresh the page:

```
Object { stack: "AxiosError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49751:18\nhandleAbort@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49125:14\nEventHandlerNonNull*dispatchXhrRequest@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49121:5\n./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js/__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49032:10\ndispatchRequest@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50232:10\nrequest@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49668:77\nhttpMethod@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49702:19\nwrap@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50799:15\nMakePost@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:444:53\nonClick@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:561:24\ncallCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14402:18\ninvokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14446:20\ninvokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14503:35\ninvokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14517:29\nexecuteDispatch@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18660:46\nprocessDispatchQueueItemsInOrder@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18686:26\nprocessDispatchQueue@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18697:41\ndispatchEventsForPlugins@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18706:27\n./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18866:16\nbatchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33250:16\nbatchedUpdates@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14250:16\ndispatchEventForPluginEventSystem@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18865:21\ndispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16372:42\ndispatchEvent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16366:88\ndispatchDiscreteEvent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16343:22\n", message: "Request aborted", name: "AxiosError", code: "ECONNABORTED", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
bundle.js:454:31
```

Comment: in makePost Method you are calling a post api with async and await,  you will not get any data in response as you are not returning anything after the api is successfull.

Comment: I removed async but I save same bug again:

Comment: if you are removing async await you have to use .then for post call and write rest of the two apis inside .then.  can you please create codesandbox for this

Comment: Can you recommend me video on youtube for it?

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-axios-post-requests/

you can read about this here